# Adding delta symbol in field cell for shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I'm just trying to add a delta symbol to label a feature for a shapefile in QGIS. I do this by typing the label in the appropriate cell during an editing session. I've tried copying and pasting Δ and it turns into a question mark for my label after saving the edits. I've also tried the ALT+30 method that produces the filled-in variety ▲. The same thing happens; it turns into a question mark after saving the edit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could be an issue of encoding. Please provide more details: what kind of layer do you use (Shepfile, Geopackage etc.). Try to export your layer and set encoding to UTF-8 and try again: does this help?

Comment: Great this worked! It was a shapefile by the way. I didn't even know you could set the character encoding in QGIS when you used the Save As option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [@babel's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360320/adding-delta-symbol-in-field-cell-for-shapefile-in-qgis#comment589391_360320):

> Could be an issue of encoding. Please provide more details: what kind
>   of layer do you use (Shepfile, Geopackage etc.). Try to export your
>   layer and set encoding to UTF-8 and try again: does this help?

I used the Save As option for my shapefile and set the encoding to UTF-8. Then I just copied and pasted Δ in the cell and it remained after saving the edit.